# Ethereum vs bitcoin technology

Tags: bitcoin, proof-of-work

I have understood how bitcoin works (coinbase block, mining, links between transactions, hashrate, nounce, proof of work, ...)

Now i want to understand how Ethereum works.
Can we say it is the same concept than bitcoin but extended with smart contracts ?

Or is it something radically different ?

Basically i want to know if there are a maximum amount of ETH that will be forged each time a new block is mined ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! that's the main difference. However, there are other important differences that are less obvious (UTXO, hashing algorithm, etc).
You can see Bitcoin as a decentralized payment system, and Ethereum as a SuperComputer to power dApps on top of that.

Unlike Bitcoin with its supply capped at 21 million, Ethereum has no limit on its total coin supply.

Comment: Thanks, there are no UTXO equivalent on Ethereum ?

Comment: Ethereum is account-based